# How do I make Media Player Classic play audio files seamlessly?

Tags: audio, winamp, media-player-classic

If you've used Winamp, you know it can play files in a playlist without a noticeable delay. Other players, however, don't do that for various reasons. I'd like to know if it's possible to enable seamless playback in my favorite player, Media Player Classic.

Comment: Do you mean instantly switching from one file to the next, or a crossfade effect?

Comment: The first thing. No delay between the end of the current file and the beginning of the next one in folder/playlist.

Comment: This is known as [gapless playback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapless_playback). Looks like a feature request was added for MPC [4 years ago](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/1834) and 5 months ago a minor edit was made. I don't believe it's supported at this time.